How can I use Powershell with the Terraform external data provider
I have a simple Terraform module using the external data source:
data "external" "steptemplate_validate_password_stores" {
  program = ["pwsh", "-Command", "$query = Read-Host  | ConvertFrom-JSON\n$headers = @{ \"X-Octopus-ApiKey\" = $query.apikey }\n$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri \"$($query.server)/api/$($query.spaceid)/actiontemplates?take=10000\" -Method GET -Headers $headers\n$keyValueResponse = @{}\n$response.content | ConvertFrom-JSON | Select-Object -Expand Items | ? {$_.Name -eq $query.name} | % {$keyValueResponse[$_.Id] = $_.Name} | Out-Null\n$results = $keyValueResponse | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 100\nWrite-Host $results"]
  query   = { apikey = "API-xxx", name = "Validate Password Stores", server = "https://yourinstance.octopus.app", spaceid = "Spaces-1234" }
}

Despite everything appearing to work, this example produces the error:
│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│ 
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│ 
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
│ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
│ 
│ Program: /usr/bin/pwsh
│ Result Error: invalid character '{' after top-level value

What is wrong with this example?

Answering this one because it took a bit to debug.
The issue is this line in the script:
$query = Read-Host  | ConvertFrom-JSON

Replacing this with the following code fixed the issue:
$query = [Console]::In.ReadLine() | ConvertFrom-JSON

I suspect Read-Host is actually printing something to the output despite there being no prompt, and this is tripping up the data provider.

Nice find, don't forget to accept your own answer. $Host.UI.ReadLine() would probably do the trick too
